# Payment processing using Java Script in Authorize.net

Tags: authorize.net

I am using the authorize.net payment gateway using **Direct Post Method.**

[EDIT] **Because of CARD PRESENT**

### Following Steps I am using currently:

#1: Collecting credit card information

#2: Sending details to My APP Server

#3: Calling the Direct Post Method API of Authorize.net through My APP Server.

```
But Because of Step 2, I need to make my server to be PCI-DSS compliance.
```

### But If I use Stripe Payment Gateway it provides,

#1: Collecting credit card information [ They have written [their own JavaScript](https://js.stripe.com/v2/) ]

#2: Create a single use token [ Java scripts sent call to Stripe API and returns the some token]

#3: Now I can use the token for the other processing in the my APP server.

```
Because of the above approach I don't need to make my server to be 
PCI-DSS compliance.
```

So I am looking forward to use SECOND type of approach if authorize.net provide ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to avoid PCI compliance you can use the [Simple Integration Method](http://developer.authorize.net/api/sim/) or [Direct Post Method](http://developer.authorize.net/api/dpm/). Both do not require you handling customer data as the process is done on Authorize.Net's servers.

Comment: I am using Card Present, Does it provide for Card Present also ?

Comment: I don't think so. Their Card Present works differently.